# PHP send mail with PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am try to create `PHPMailer` with this:

```
<?php

include('class.phpmailer.php');

try {
    echo "Test";
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    echo "Test2";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
?>
```

And only the first `Test` is print. Any idea what can be the problem?

Comment: Turn errors on.  Are you sure the path is correct?
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

Comment: Thank you!! i find the problem with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn errors on. Are you sure the path is correct?

```
<?php    
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Should give you a good place to start.